# What do crescendo/diminuendo marks mean when no accompanying text?

Tags: voice, sheet-music

In the first page we have a solo verse. It starts *mp*and then builds to *mf* over one bar. But then in the bottom line we drop to *p*... But then the bottom line and top of page two we drop and build when we're already in *p*. Does that mean

> Snow... on snow

Is dropping from *p* to *pp* then crescendoing back up to *p*?

Also since this is a solo, when it says *mp* does that mean I am singing *mp* or that the overall volume is *mp* relative to the whole choir ie I need to be quite loud?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess there's nowhere much to go below 'p' other than 'pp', so we can excuse a bit of sloppy notation.  It really should have been marked though, if only to avoid queries such as yours!

At the beginning, the piano is marked 'p', the voice 'mp'.  That's meticulously correct.  It would have probably been OK to mark both the same.  I don't think there's much chance that the pianist would try to dominate.

I don't see a 'mp' where the choir are singing?  When they enter, everyone has 'f'.  When the melody is in the top part, we probably don't have to over-think this, it will 'come through' automatically.

All dynamics are relative.  Yes, it's a 'solo mp'.  Treat it as a feeling as much as a reading on a dB meter!  The actual power you use will vary with the size of room and other factors.

We sometimes have to be over-meticulous when notating for computer playback.  Live performers listen to each other (hopefully).

Comment: But broadly speaking if I see mp for a solo verse, I am aiming to produce the same volume as the choir at mp? Because pp for a solo singer is going to be very quiet otherwise!

Comment: I've never sung a solo, or in a big church room (un-micced) - no idea how to gauge my volume so anyone can actually hear ;)

Comment: A choir at 'mp' is going to sound very different to a soloist at 'mp'.  But the measured volume might not be much different.  Partly because volume isn't simply additive - two singers are not twice as loud as one, or twenty singers twenty times as loud.  Partly because real musicians aren't computers who see 'mp' and pump out a fixed level - they LISTEN and do what is required to deliver the desired effect.   In this case you need to 'fill the room' but with a 'mp' feel.  Yes, all very subjective!  Your choir director will soon tell you if you're not judging it well.  Let him help you. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe we should attach paramount importance to *all* the dynamic marks. It may well be that they are put in by the publishers, rather than the writer, and as such, are whimsical.

More to the point, they're only advisory. It's your solo, so you must sing as you feel fit. As long as you are audible above the choir and accompanist, the job is yours. Can you honestly expect *anyone* afterwards to say ' that crescendo/rall. etc. wasn't the best'?!

That apart, as Laurence says, it's more dependent on the acoustics and balance in the room concerned on the day concerned. And do not forget that during any rehearsal prior, lack of absorbent bodies will give a very different dynamic to it all anyway.